# Why is the Firebase console asking me to implement the SDK when it is already integrated with my Android & iOS app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-ads-api, firebase-performance

The Firebase Code is already implemented on my Android & iOS app- Already able to view the App Analytics for these Apps on the console. 
However, when going to Console > Quality > Performance view, the message prompts me to install the SDK for more actionable insights into the Apps performance & latencies.
Same error is popping across different Firebase projects for other apps too. Is this a common occurence or is this indicative of any inherent flaws with my integration mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK's include multiple components so that apps can use some Firebase capabilities without linking all of Firebase into their app.

For example, on iOS, Firebase Performance is delivered in a different CocoaPod from Firebase Analytics. Therefore the Performance CocoaPod needs to be installed in addition to Analytics:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
```

Details at https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios